# Obtener las custom url de un canal con la API de Youtube

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Tengo que obtener las `custom url` de varios canales.
He estaba buscando información al respecto pero no he encontrado nada aun, el motivo es porque necesito incrustarlos en un reporte de esta forma

```
youtube.com/c/YouTubeCreators
```

entiendo que no todos los canales tiene `custom url` o bien no han cumplido los requisitos mínimos para esa funcionalidad...

He intentado realizando algunas consultas con la `YouTube Data API` mediante el ***sandbox*** que ofrece google para pruebas, entre estas consultas están

[Data API Channels: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22snippet%22%2C%22topicDetails%22%2C%22id%22%2C%22contentDetails%22%5D%2C%22mine%22%3Atrue%7D)

pero no me devuelve los datos que necesito, también intenté con:

[Data API Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22snippet%22%2C%22id%22%5D%2C%22channelId%22%3A%22UC7pJwIBB7YneW_FOhqqkRpw%22%2C%22type%22%3A%5B%22channel%22%5D%7D)

Otra cosas podría ser obtener el `username` pero igual no he encontrado informacion al respecto

Comment: Hola amigo, He verificado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask], Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: y que has intentado???

Comment: he intentado desde la api con esta consulta https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22snippet%22%2C%22topicDetails%22%2C%22id%22%2C%22contentDetails%22%5D%2C%22mine%22%3Atrue%7D pero no me devuelve los datos que necesito, también intenté con https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22snippet%22%2C%22id%22%5D%2C%22channelId%22%3A%22UC7pJwIBB7YneW_FOhqqkRpw%22%2C%22type%22%3A%5B%22channel%22%5D%7D

Comment: ok te explico lo siguiente: en el sitio esperamos que nos demuestres el código que tu has creado para intentar solucionar el problema; no seguimos tutoriales para comprobar si el tutorial tiene problemas ... te sugiero que documentes en tu post todo lo que has realizado y que código has intentando implementar y que error te da ese código (error especifico) para nosotros poder trabajar y darte una buena respuesta. de lo contrario tu post posiblemente sea cerrado o reciba votos negativos.

Comment: Es que antes de llevarlo a codigo pruebo con el sandbox que ofrece google y que permite hacer las querys como las que mencioné anteriormente

Comment: Deberías agregar ese danto entonces es crucial para poder hacer pruebas de lo que intentas hacer..

Comment: Listo, ya lo agregué

Comment: ok, le hice unos retoques al post; puedes aclararme algo; que informacion tienes para conseguir las custom URL???

Answer (score 0):

En esta respuesta voy a asumir que usted posee el `channel_id` de antemano que desea obtener la información que requiere - en su [ejemplo](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22snippet%22%2C%22id%22%5D%2C%22channelId%22%3A%22UC7pJwIBB7YneW_FOhqqkRpw%22%2C%22type%22%3A%5B%22channel%22%5D%7D) sería: **`UC7pJwIBB7YneW_FOhqqkRpw`**.

En mis pruebas, ese valor se llama "`cannonicalBaseUrl`"; por lo que, para obtener esta URL, debe seguir varios pasos:

1. Debe obtener el `video_id` de un video que sea del canal que desea usar - para esta prueba, voy a usar el video_id **`ooqaELbiaRU`** que pertenece al canal **`UC7pJwIBB7YneW_FOhqqkRpw`**.
2. Use este endpoint para obtener el valor "author_url":

> `https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<VIDEO_ID>&format=json`

Donde **`<VIDEO_ID>`** es reemplazado por **`ooqaELbiaRU`**.

El resultado de ejecutar el [endpoint con el video_id de esta prueba](https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ooqaELbiaRU&format=json) es el siguiente:

```
{
    "title": "Deja que la inspiraci\u00f3n te gu\u00ede",
    "author_name": "Kia Puerto Rico",
    "author_url": "https://www.youtube.com/user/kiapuertorico",
    "type": "video",
    "height": 113,
    "width": 200,
    "version": "1.0",
    "provider_name": "YouTube",
    "provider_url": "https://www.youtube.com/",
    "thumbnail_height": 360,
    "thumbnail_width": 480,
    "thumbnail_url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ooqaELbiaRU/hqdefault.jpg",
    "html": "\u003ciframe width=\u0022200\u0022 height=\u0022113\u0022 src=\u0022https://www.youtube.com/embed/ooqaELbiaRU?feature=oembed\u0022 frameborder=\u00220\u0022 allow=\u0022accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture\u0022 allowfullscreen\u003e\u003c/iframe\u003e"
}
```

De la respuesta anterior, ya puede obtener el "`cannonicalBaseUrl`" ó **`author_url`**:

> `"author_url": "https://www.youtube.com/user/kiapuertorico"`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la API [**oEmbed**](https://oembed.com/), la cual te permitirá mostrar el ontenido que se puede embeber a partir de una url de un contenido, pero en este caso además puedes obtener mas información como autor, url de autor, tipo, medidas, proveedor, etc

```
https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=<URL VIDEO>&format=<FORMATO JSON o XML>
```

Ejemplo

https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VW7afIUk-ik&format=json

se obtiene la información:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la información que buscas sería el valor de

```
"author_url"
```